# How does Ubuntu's install CD file integrity self-check work (checksum, corrupt, digest)

Tags: system-installation, checksums, hash, sha256, sha256sum

How does the Ubuntu Install disk verify its own integrity after boot and before install?

I'm very familiar with the process to do a manual check of the integrity of a Linux distro's .iso file with a cryptographic hash stored in a (hopefully signed) digest file like `SHA256SUMS` using a command like

```
sha256sum --check SHA256SUMS
```

But I've also seen that, When installing Ubuntu via CD or USB drive, it can [verify its own integrity](https://askubuntu.com/a/1311197)!

How does this actually work, internally? What tools are used? Where is the sourcecode for this check?

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091335/create-checksum-sha256-of-all-files-and-directories

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1406136/edit) and add all the additional information and links in your question. The comments are mainly our channel to ask for clarification and let you know if there is a problem with your question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are referring to is handled by [Casper](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper).

When the ISO boots the service [`casper.casper-md5check.service`](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/tree/debian/casper.casper-md5check.service?id=db8f8bfa4f72813d72ef18085c67c4610a933830) is run.  This service calls the binary [`casper-md5check`](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/tree/casper-md5check/casper-md5check.c?id=db8f8bfa4f72813d72ef18085c67c4610a933830).  The arguments to the binary tell it to verify checksums defined in `/cdrom/md5sum.txt`.

The results of the verification are written to `/run/casper-md5check.json`.

The `service` is fairly new.  The verification used to run from a script in the initramfs.

I'm not sure what part of the ISO build process creates the `md5sum.txt` file.